# Windows Azure VM Role Deployment Issue & 'Beta Programs' missing from portal

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_vmrolelab_topic2).
Scroll down to, Task 5 – Creating the Service Model

On Step 4 i.e.
"4.Once the solution is created, right-click the Roles folder inside the MyVMRole project, point to Add, and then select New Virtual Machine Role."

The 'New Virtual Machine Role' option doesn't appear on my VS.
This of course is because, I haven't got an invite into the beta program of MS Azure VM Role and haven't installed the VS tool.

My question is how do I join the beta program or apply for this tool?

I saw some online posts to go to Azure Management Portal -> Home -> Beta Programs.
But for me, the 'Beta Programs' folder doesn't appear in the portal. Please help.

Comment: As mentioned below, I can't give you an explanation for why the signup option has been removed. Having said that: Have you looked into working with Web Roles and Worker Roles (basically Windows 2008 Server VMs that you don't have to manage)? I think you'll find them far easier to work with, and they don't require you to build and upload a vhd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently the VM Role signup option stopped showing up on the portal. Access to VM Role Beta signup has been available for quite awhile. Unfortunately I cannot provide any reason behind the removal of the signup option.

**EDIT**: You should still be able to gain access if you contact Support and request it. Also: This only impacts new signups for VM Role Beta; existing access should remain unaffected (just to be safe, I double-checked my own account - everything's still there, nothing changed).

**EDIT** With the new portal update that just rolled out, you'll now find Virtual Machines signup at https://account.windowsazure.com/PreviewFeatures

Comment: Yeah David, thats what I did and it sorted now. The Microsoft Support enabled the VM Role features on my account. The documentation doesn't clearly state certain stuff (as links to toolkits, Beta Page etc) and makes the links go round in a loop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's still in beta, you can sign up [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/?WT.mc_id=src-n-gb--Cdev--&WT.srch=1) for a free trial.

If you just need to install the SDK for development you should only need to download that and the tools from [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/#setup)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows Azure signup. The option has simply disappeared from the Windows Azure portal (for reasons undisclosed).